# Hook api from the device driver with python

Tags: python, windows, api, hook, device-driver

I want to develop a python script to hook functions of the windows api, but without the need to inject in the process to be done the hook. I heard it's possible making access to the device driver and do hook from it, I searched but did not find ways to do this, does anyone know a lib, or ways of doing this access to device driver?

Comment: I understood all of those words individually... but not all together like you have them

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can access DLL functions via python with the [ctypes library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).